# Spring Ampq type name and EasyNetQ

Tags: java, c#, spring-boot, spring-amqp, easynetq

I need send message between `C#` Microservices with EasyNetQ and `Java` with Spring Amqp.

The problem is the properties message , the Type from Spring Boot Amqp is in property `__type__` headers container while in EasynetQ is expected from outher properties named `type`.

Could anyone tell me what i need to customize to let comunicate them as well?

```
Spring Amqp :
    "Headers":{"__TypeId__":"com.fastdeliveryservice.service.Info"}

   EasynetQ: 
      "type" : "com.fastdeliveryservice.service.Info"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` by configuring its `Jackson2JavaTypeMapper` with a customized one. Subclass the `DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper` and override the `getClassIdFieldName()` method to return `type` instead of `__TypeId__`.

Comment: hi i did it but it's still inside "headers" array instead out of it , sibilling other proprierties like reply_to: etc. Other question , it's possibile to ovveride the ""com.fastdeliveryservice.service.Info" namespace?

Comment: Ah; sorry - missed that; you can use a `MessagePostProcessor` to set the `type` property for outgoing messages and a similar one to copy the type to the typeId header for inbound messages (in `afterReceivePostProcessors`). Alternatively, customize the message converter to use the `type` property.

Comment: Thanks. I did it! There a Field Type not setted so i used it!